# Java Flight Recorder (JFR) from command line: [jfr] [ERROR] [1014.291] Repository could not be removed at shutdown

Tags: java, jfr

I'm following course on Java Flight Recorder usage [java-flight-recorder-monitoring](https://www.baeldung.com/java-flight-recorder-monitoring).

I compiled a java code from example (adding `class` and `imports` because it did not compile w/out them):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class TestFlightRecorder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>(1);
    try {
        while (true){
            items.add(new Object());
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    assert items.size() > 0;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Then I run as per course:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin>java
>   -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+F lightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=200s,filename=c:\am\out\flight.j fr -cp c:\am\out TestFlightRecorder

Output right after:

> Started recording 1. The result will be written to:
>
> C:\AM\out\flight.jfr

Memory usage in Windows task manager of java goes up, then after much more than 200 seconds:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>           at TestFlightRecorder.main(TestFlightRecorder.java:12) [jfr][ERROR][1014.291] Repository could not be removed at shutdown

And resulting `flight.jfr` have size of 0 bytes. (when I made the same command with simple hello world java class, flight.jfr was created with size 125Kb with 'empty' info inside - that I guess is due to the fact app worked so quickly flight recording had not started yet - and this question is not about that emptiness).

Web search for such error was w/out results. Why error, have I done something incorrectly to make a recording?

Comment: Shouldn't your `Thread.sleep` be inside the `while(true)` loop? As it is your code will rush to the OOMError which likely disrupts the JVM enough that the flightrecorder fails to write its "empty info" to its log file, displaying the error you saw

Comment: @Aaron, 'empty info' could be unrelated, I wrote about it to show jfr generally works on that workstation. As for OOM, course said that error is part of idea of app "Our program inserts objects into a list until an OutOfMemoryError occurs." If we just move sleep inside loop, memory will grow too slow for the learning exercise as far as I understood.

Comment: Do you already know what result is expected? Because otherwise "Encountering an OOM makes FlightRecorder fail" seems like it could be the expected conclusion.

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce your problem, each time I run your code I get some flight recording data, probably because of different memory settings. Still, I can  suggest you remove the catch and the thread.sleep, having the list init and the `while(true)` loop alone is enough to satisfy your requirements, and having a 1-second wait during which the list is still in-scope probably worsen the situation.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you for your input about "OOMError which likely disrupts the JVM enough that the flightrecorder fails to write", I ran the code with setting for 20s and got resulting recording with graphs similar to course. So I consider current issue solved.

Answer (score 2):

Java Flight Recorder writes the dump in a Java shutdown hook when the application ends. If there is not enough memory to produce the dump it will fail.

The error happens because the file is still held by the JVM while the shutdown hook thread tries to remove it.

Comment: In my command jfr was set for 200 sec timeframe. You write about case of app termination. I could not see how your answer applies.

Comment: If you make a recording with a duration, a dump will be created when the application ends, which I assumed is what happened when the application runs out of memory.

Comment: In general, in a low memory environment a lot of things could go wrong in the JFR code that is written in Java. JFR creates at least two other threads that also allocate memory, and if they run into OOME before the main thread, things will break.

Answer (score 1):

Hinted by comment made by Aaron:

> OOMError which likely disrupts the JVM enough that the flightrecorder
>   fails to write

I ran the code with recoding time of 20s, not 200s (in task manager I saw java memory usage grow to max heap of 2Gb in about that time too) and got resulting recording with graphs similar to presented in the course. So I consider current issue solved.